# Redirect variable to stdin

Tags: c, bash, redirect, pipe, stdin

I am trying to run pipe bash commands such as `ls | wc -l` in a C program. My approach was to save stdout in a pipe every time a command different from the last one is executed using the following line:

```
write(fd[1], stdout, sizeof(stdout))
```

Then. fd[0] should set the value of stdin for the next child execution. My approach was to use a command similar to freopen(). The problem is that this command does not redirect the values from a variable to stdin, so it does not help reading fd[0]. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just use pipe: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html

Comment: `write(fd[1], stdout, sizeof(stdout));` writes the value of a pointer to your pipe.  I'm not sure what you expected that to do?

Comment: I think what you actually want is something like `dup2(pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);` in your child process and `dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);` in your parent process (assuming you want normal printf's etc. from the parent to go to the child).